# Difference between 'As compared to' and 'When compared to'

Tags: phrases, comparisons

Is there any rule governing when the phrase "As compared to..." should be used, and when "When compared to..." should be used? Or, do they mean the same, in all contexts?

Comment: "As compared to" could be used usually in places where the two ideas are usually compared. While "When compared to" is used when two ideas are normally never or rarely compared which brings forth "usually" a realization moment the difference (the word "when" brings forth this notion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this :

Both forms occur in objective writing, but "when compared to" occurs more often in personal and persuasive writing.

"As compared to" is the standard form in the reporting of statistics from research. It's used in scientific, technical, and business writing. It's very impersonal.

"When compared to" is a short form of "when one compares (X) to (Y)," and is used when the act of comparison itself is relevant. This form also occurs in persuasive writing, when the writer seems to be asking the reader to do the comparing. Given the context, Sentence 1 is more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! It would be great if you could provide references, if they exist.

Comment: Sure! When I compared the new edition with the old one, I found the former to be far more interesting. Same sentence can be written like this : The new edition is farm more interesting as compared to the old one. Both imply the same meaning but the second one is more formal.